# Insert current date Teradata

Tags: teradata

```
SELECT  DATE(FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd') (CHAR(10)) --2013-12-12

SELECT  DATE(FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd') --12/12/2013
```

I like to insert data into table in this format

```
insert into emp values ( DATE(FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd') (CHAR(10)) ,...... )
```

can you tell me how to insert current date into table 
in this format ?
yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your actual problem? FORMAT is mainly used for CASTs from/to a string, but the internal datatype DATE is not stored in any dmy/ymd format.

If the target column is defined as a DATE you can simply insert DATE/CURRENT_DATE without applying a FORMAT to it.

Your 2nd example showing a wrong result is probably submitted using SQL Assistant, which is using its own formating rules based on Options -> Data Format -> "Display dates in this format".

Your INSERT will be correct for a CHAR target column, but you shouldn't store dates in a CHAR :-)

Comment: Thanks Doneth , I was able to figure out .

Answer (score 0):

```
CYCLEDATE DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'    --- TABLE DEFINITION

Insert into emp cycledate values ( date ) -- worked .
```